# Where does pyramid store the auth_tkt session cookie at rest

Tags: python, pyramid

Where does Pyramid store the auth_tkt at rest? I'm trying to quantify how many open sessions my site currently has and I'm hoping I'm just blanking on what table it's being stored at.

Answer (score 0):

`auth_tkt` is the default name of the cookie which is a parameter for Pyramid's [`AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy`](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/authentication.html#pyramid.authentication.AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy), which is stored in the visitor's web browser.

Pyramid has no database, but your app might have one. If so, then you'll need to trace through your application's code to find where you maintain server side sessions.

Comment: If Pyramid has no db, does it even save a local copy of the session or is the fact the cookie signed that it doesn't need to store a local copy?

Comment: Pyramid itself stores nothing. Your app may use any persistence system, including a database or writing to disk, to store data on the server. If you want to track the number of users who are authenticated and associated data, then you'll need to use a package or write your own. Here's a list of add-ons that you can filter by Auths: https://trypyramid.com/resources-extending-pyramid.html

Answer (score 0):

To extend on Steve's answer: auth_tkt is an authentication method which does not require a server-side session storage. It works by generating a cookie based on username and a server-side *secret*, so the cookie basically looks like this:

```
senatork:kuh87h887KHJKJH908uo
```

The client then sends the cookie and the server is able to validate the "claim" contained in the "ticket" by generating a new signature using the server-side secret and comparing it to the one contained in the cookie. Here's some more details in the documentation of the original [Apache mod_auth_tkt](http://www.openfusion.com.au/labs/mod_auth_tkt/) (which Pyramid does not use, but it uses the same logic).

If you need a session storage for your app you'll need to implement it separately from auth_tkt authentication.

Comment: Makes sense. I was wrongfully assuming it was storing a local copy. Thanks.